# Matlab Newton's Method Code

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to write a Matlab code for a Numerical Analysis class I am in. We are to create a matrix entitled 'picture' which corresponds to a 1000 x 1000 array which evenly covers the square [-1,1] x [-1,1] in the complex plane. Each of these 1000000 points must be compared to the roots of the function f(x)=x^3 + 1 (which are 1, (1+sqrt(3)i)/2, and (1-sqrt(3)i)/2, I believe). Using Newton's Method and each of the 1000000 points as our initial approximation, we are supposed to get an approximation of a root of the function at each point. Then if the norm(approximate root minus one of the 3 actual roots) is less than a user-defined tolerance, we make that point in the 1000 x 1000 array one of 4 color codes: 0, 20, 40, or 60. Essentially each point (and corresponding approximate root) will be a different color depending on which of the actual roots it is closest to.
I have been working on this code for so long and I can't be more specific about my problem because I just have no idea where I am going wrong. I have attached my code in the hopes that somebody might read it and see a horrible (yet easily fixable) mistake! Every time I run the code I get a huge matrix of zeros.

```
function [] = coloredroots()
nPoints = 1000;

picture = zeros(nPoints, nPoints);

for a = 1 : nPoints
    for b = 1 : nPoints
        double z;
        z = (-1 + (a*0.002)) + 1i*(-1 + (b*0.002));  %%z is complex number,0.002 is the    %%increment size that allows 1000 steps between -1 and 1

f = @(x) (x^3) + 1;   %%the function we are finding the roots of
fprime = @(x) 3*(x^2);
nmax = 100;   %%maximum number of iterations of Newton's method
error= 10^(-1);    %%user-created max error
tolerance = 10^(-1);    %%how close we want the approx roots to be to the actual roots, %% also user-created
double code;

    root = newton(f, fprime, (-1 + (a*(0.002))), nmax, error);
    code = getColorCode(root, tolerance);
    picture(a,b) = code;  %%storing the color code found using initial approximation of %%point (a,b) into the matrix 'picture' in row a, column b
end
end

image(picture)
print('plot_coloredroots', '-dpng');  
%%My teacher instructed us to include these 2 above lines although I am yet to define a      %%plot 

function [x] = newton(f, fprime, x, nmax, error)

for n = 1:nmax
    d = f(x)/fprime(x);
    x = x - d;
    if abs(d) < error
        return
    end
end
end

function [c] = getColorCode(root, tolerance)
if norm(root - 1.0) < tolerance
    c = 20;
elseif norm(root - (0.5*sqrt(3)*1i - 0.5)) < tolerance
    c = 40;
elseif norm(root - (-0.5*sqrt(3)*1i - 0.5)) < tolerance
    c = 60;
else
    c = 0;
end
end
end
```

Comment: If you can't see where a bug lies directly, you should try to narrow it down. Try replacing `getColorCode` with something that returns a constant- is your matrix filled with that constant? What if it just returns `root` or `tolerance`? Does your matrix get filled with the expected values for those parameters? If `root` is the problem, then maybe try coping `newton` into a new file and trying different inputs to that, etc.

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem is how I store the color codes in the matrix and how I attempt to then convert that matrix to a picture. I know that newton is correct as I first wrote that code in its own script. I will try your other suggestions, thank you for reading my problem!